# options for controlling UX of Bot Framework in ionic app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3, botframework

Bot Builder newbie here...

The [Microsoft QnA Maker](https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/quickstart) makes it really easy to get started with Cognitive Services because once you have your FAQ content loaded and the URL is set, you can interact with that URL in a simple web page. This allows a developer full control of how the content is styled and rendered within the web page, because you're playing with JSON content.

I'm trying to better understand the options available to a developer when using the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/).

If I want to make a mobile app with the Ionic framework, it is (relatively) trivial to interact with the QnA web service and style the output. What if I wanted to make a mobile app with the Ionic framework and use a Bot Builder chatbot, though?

**What are the options one has for UX (styling and formatting of responses) using the Bot Builder framework when you are NOT using QnA Maker? Does the "dialog" for the Bot Builder have to be embedded as an external control, thereby significantly reducing what the developer can control?**

From what I can gather, nothing here is as trivial as the QnA Maker;
i.e., the Bot Builder Framework seems more complex than simply interacting with POST responses - "[Easy: In your non-React website, run Web Chat inline](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)"
The story of why the Bot Builder is more complex is not clear enough for me. It seems that it is has these "black box" aspects that make it more than a response of JSON and something that has to be "embedded" one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

if you're just looking to style responses for QnA maker, two blog posts detail this:

[QnA maker for Node.js bots](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/17/qna-maker-node-js-bots/)

[QnA maker and rich cards .NET](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/08/25/qna-maker-rich-card-attachments-net/)

Your options are to use the built-in card attachments, or to be more flexible, you can use an [adaptive card](http://adaptivecards.io/)

Hope that helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link for QnA Maker. Sorry if my question was not clear enough, or perhaps my question reflects my lack of understanding of the Bot Framework. I was thinking of the case where I'm using the formal (?) Bot Framework, **not** using QnA Maker, which MS seems to separate somewhat from the Bot Framework.

Comment: I see - If you're trying to style activities/messages from your bot then you have a few options available - [Add rich cards to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards). If you want more flexibility, then you can also use [adaptive cards](http://adaptivecards.io/), which is newer and still growing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one last UI option - You can also change the styling of the Web Chat controller itself - [Customize Web Chat](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/). Since you're developing a mobile app via iconic framework, this might be closer to what you're looking for. The Web Chat controller itself is built with Typescript + React.